# Sort list using benchmark list

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list with benchmark order of items:

```
benchmark = ['Wind', 'Sun', 'Tree', 'Human', 'Cat']
```

Also I have many small lists with two items:

```
list1 = ['Cat', 'Wind']
list2 = ['Tree', 'Sun']
list3 = ['Wind', 'Human']
```

I want to sort them using order in benchmark. So expected output is:

```
list1 = ['Wind', 'Cat']
list2 = ['Sun', 'Tree']
list3 = ['Wind', 'Human']
```

How can I do it in most efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
benchmark = ['Wind', 'Sun', 'Tree', 'Human', 'Cat']
list1 = ['Cat', 'Wind']
list2 = ['Tree', 'Sun']
list3 = ['Wind', 'Human']

print(sorted(list1, key=benchmark.index))
print(sorted(list2, key=benchmark.index))
print(sorted(list3, key=benchmark.index))
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `zip` function

```
sorted_list1 = [item for _,item in sorted(zip(benchmark,list1))]
```

Comment: Your code works whan I use English words. But order doesn't change with Russian words. Is it Cyrillic problem?